# PHP execution timeout in SqliteProfilerStorage

Tags: symfony, profiler, execution-time

In my Symfony2 application, I am getting the following error at the time of login. If we refresh the page once again, the error will disappear.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
in SqliteProfilerStorage.php on line 84
```

What will be the reason?

Comment: Do you get it each time? Do you also get it in a production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove by hand the file in `app/cache/dev/profiler.db`. It happens when the DB size is getting big even on SSD disks.

You can add some 30s to exec time in `php.ini`.

If the situation will keep you can disable symfony profiler in config_dev.yml